# Angular:Redux and Lazy loading

Tags: angular, typescript, redux

I am using the design pattern of Redux with Angular and I find it very useful, but how redux and lazy loading can leave toghether?

Comment: are you using ngrx or angular-redux or an answer for either is acceptable?

Comment: I am using ngrx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you don't state whether you are using or plan to use ngrx or angular-redux I will assume the more popular ngrx.

With ngrx you can load reducers and effects on initialisation. By default, the /src/app/reducers/index.ts will define your reducers with something like this:

```
export interface AppState {
  router: any,
  simpro: BimState,
  omnipresent: OmniState,
  user: UserState
}

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<AppState> = {
  router: routerReducer,
  simpro: bimReducer,
  omnipresent: omniReducer,
  user: userReducer
}
```

The state and reducers defined here are always accessible.

However, if you have a portion of state that pertains only to a single lazily loaded route module, then you can add the state and the reducer to that specific module.

State and reducers loaded in this manner only take effect / appear in the Redux Devtools state tree when the route in question is activated and the module is loaded. So you must ensure they are not accessed in any code where they may not yet exist, e.g. in another lazily loaded module.

Similar logic applies to effects, they can be loaded in the root module or within a lazily loaded module.